# cakephp 1.2 requestAction pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using Cakephp 1.2. I should be able to sort by A-Z or Z-A with the paginate. However, I got this error below. No much information found in the other resources. please help.

Notice (8): Undefined variable: paginator [APP/views/elements/products.ctp, line 25]
Fatal error: Call to a member function sort() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/development03/app/views/elements/products.ctp on line 25

**Controller**

```
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Ajax','Javascript', 'Text');

// Pagination 
var $paginate = array('limit' => 8, 'page' => 1,'order'=>array('Product.name' => 'asc'));
```

function lists() {

```
    $categories = $this->Category->find('all', array('order' => 'Category.id ASC' ));       
    $categories = $this->Category->buildCategories($categories, $this->passedArgs['c']);
    $children_ids  = $this->Category->getChildCategories($categories, $this->passedArgs['c'], true);
    $allCatIds = array_merge(array($this->passedArgs['c']), $children_ids);
    //return lists
    return $this->Product->lists($allCatIds);
}
```

Element

```
<?php 

$products = $this->requestAction("/products/lists/c:$catId/"); 

?>

 <?php echo $paginator->sort('Name', 'name', array('title' => 'Sorting Title Alphabetically','class' => 'normalTip')); ?>

<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
 ...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the paginator class in your element, you must have to include the helper class in your controller. So your controller's code will looks like :

```
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Ajax','Javascript', 'Text', 'Paginator');
```

More Explanation:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function sort() on a non-object" comes when you are trying to access the method through an object which never been instantiated by any class. So your application must know which kind of object it is.

Kindly ask if it not worked.

Comment: thanks Arun Jain. Slight improvement. How do I add the paginator in my above mentioned controller? I got this error after I included the helper class. Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/paginator.php, line 139]
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE/cake/libs/view/helpers/paginator.php, line 277]

Comment: I'll take few minutes to answer you.

Comment: You are using lists() method in a wrong way. This link must help you. http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/view/165/Controller-Setup . Instead of returning query result you should use $this->paginate('Product'); and use all the conditions with $paginate array.

Comment: yes. this is the norm method. i often use this too. however, for this page. i using requestAction method. so i have no idea how can i implement pagination with requestAction

Comment: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Pagination-through-requestAction-td1267789.html and http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/gwoo/2007/04/12/creating-reusable-elements-with-requestaction links might help you exactly the same which you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like $paginator isn't set to anything.

If you put this code in your view, does it say $paginator is NULL?

```
var_dump($paginator);
```

It's hard to say from the code provided, but I assume you either

1. Aren't making $paginator available to your view in your controller
2. Are using the incorrect variable name altogether

Comment: yes is null. i have the code below for the view `<div class="center" style="width:100%;">
    <p><?php echo $paginator->numbers(); ?></p> 
    <br />
    <p><small>Showing Page <?php echo $paginator->counter(); ?></small><p>
    </div>` but it shows Notice (8): Undefined variable: paginator [APP/views/elements/products.ctp, line 97]

Comment: I think if you use Arun Jain's solution, it should work for you.